# How to get Context for ClusterManager in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-activity, android-context

Which Context i could use to init the ClusterManager in Kotlin Android?

```
var clusterManager: ClusterManager<MarkerCluster>? = null
clusterManager = ClusterManager(context, map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which Context i could use to init the ClusterManager in Kotlin Android?

Its depend on where you are using `clusterManager = ClusterManager(context, map);`

For example, if you are using it inside any activity use like this

```
clusterManager = ClusterManager(this, map); 
// or 
clusterManager = ClusterManager(this@LoginActivity, map);
```

For example, if you are using it inside any fragment use like this

```
class FragmentOne : Fragment() {

    var mContext: Context? = null

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        mContext = context

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false)
        clusterManager = ClusterManager(mContext, map)
        return rootView
    }

}
```

**NOTE**

You can use `getActivity()` and `getContext()` to get `context` inside fragment

but `getActivity()` can return `null` so i suggest you should use `onAttach()` to get `context` inside fragment